# Bash Linux: is there any way to calculate the actual % CPU used by the process

Tags: bash

Is there any way to find the actual % CPU usage(Kernel and User mode) for each processes without having to calculate from  /proc/PID/stat.  Currently i am writing a bash file to compute actual CPU usage for the processes.  PS aux only show % CPU on user mode

Answer (score 0):

Sry i think i made a mistake for not being clear.

For example, i used top to check the cpu(3 CPUs) usage and the overall CPU usage is 68.5%(100 - idle), When i added up all the CPU for all the processes and divide by 3 cpu, how come i could not get the same results(68.5%)

Cpu(s):  6.8%us, 59.0%sy,  0.0%ni, 32.5%id,  0.0%wa,  1.6%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st

```
                                      CPU
```

17980 root      20   0  103m 1204 1044 S 20.3  0.1   0:19.44 testSpeedK.sh
37213 root      20   0  103m 1204 1044 R 19.6  0.1  42:22.36 testSpeedK.sh
 2333 root      20   0  173m  42m 5708 S  3.3  2.3   5:06.73 Xorg
    7 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  2.7  0.0   3:01.22 migration/1
 2825 root      20   0  292m 9304 4456 S  2.0  0.5   0:22.87 gnome-terminal
    3 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  1.7  0.0   3:00.57 migration/0
   11 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  1.3  0.0   3:40.55 migration/2
   15 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.3  0.0   0:27.64 events/0
 1523 root      20   0  180m 2196 1712 S  0.3  0.1   0:33.01 vmtoolsd
 2657 root      20   0  438m  18m 9804 S  0.3  1.0   0:49.71 vmtoolsd
35295 root      20   0 15032 1316  952 R  0.3  0.1   0:00.04 top
    1 root      20   0 19356  972  752 S  0.0  0.1   0:01.77 init
    2 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.01 kthreadd
    4 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.42 ksoftirqd/0
    5 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 migration/0
    6 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.21 watchdog/0
    8 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 migration/1